# Django | UnboundLocalError at /station/gallery_station/2/

Tags: python, django

Al tratar de filtrar unas imágenes por id de estación a la que pertenece la imagen, me devuelve el siguiente error:
La url sí que lleba la pk correcta. Si en vez de hacer un filter, hago una select .all() devuelve todas las imagenes sin problema. Es mediante el filter con pk cuando tengo problemas.
¿Qué ocurre?

Si hago el name con un valor directo, devuelve bien:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        name = 2
        if name:
            object_list = self.model.objects.all().filter(station__id = name)
        return object_list
```

**El problema parece que está al tomar el pk de la url:**

```
name = self.request.GET.get('kword', '')
```

Gracias.

**Error:**

```
UnboundLocalError at /station/gallery_station/2/
local variable 'object_list' referenced before assignment
```

**views.py**

```
class StationGalleryListView(ListView):
    model = ImageStation
    template_name = 'station/gallery_station.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        name = self.request.GET.get('kword', '')
        if name:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(station__id = name)
        return object_list
```

**urls.py**

```
path(
    'gallery_station/<pk>/',
    views.StationGalleryListView.as_view(),
    name='gallery_station'
),
```

(url en el navegador: http://127.0.0.1:8000/station/gallery_station/2/ )

**gallery_station.html**

```
    {% for images in object_list.all %}
      <img src="/media/{{ images }}"><br>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Si el valor de `name` es None por ejemplo o `False` no entrara en el `if` por lo cual seguirá con la ejecución y intentara devolver la variable  `object_list` que solo se definirá si entra en ese `if`. Ahí esta el error

Comment: gracias Eugeni Bejan. En el ejemplo que muestro lo he reducido sin mostrar el else, pero el problema parece que está al tomar el valor pk a la variable desde la url.

Comment: Claro, porque debes de buscar el parámetro con el nombre `pk`, ya que así lo defines en la ruta. Además tienes que buscarlo en `self.kwargs`

Comment: Agradecería, si no es molestia que me concretes un poco más esa linea Eugeni Bejan, ya que no domino mucho Django. He probado name=self.kwargs['pk'] pero no lo debo estar haciendo bien.

Comment: Publicare una respuesta para aclarar mas el tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te mencione en el comentario, deberías de buscar el valor de `pk` dentro de `self.kwargs` ya que `Django` mapeara todos los parámetros de esa url dentro de la propiedad `kwargs` de tu  [Class Based View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/)

Por lo tanto tu código quedara de esta manera,

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
    # pk es el nombre de la propiedad que se creara en el dict self.kwargs con su valor
    # Por lo cual si cambias este valor por ejemplo gallery_station/<my_primary_key>/
    # deberias de buscar en los kwargs con self.kwargs['my_primary_key']
    'gallery_station/<pk>/', 
    views.StationGalleryListView.as_view(),
    name='gallery_station'
    ),
]
```

Como le estamos diciendo que `gallery_station` más un valor(en este caso cualquiera) , formaran una URL en concreto, lo cual te garantiza que siempre tendrás esa valor en tus vistas.

> Se puede declarar el tipo de dato del parámetro con `<str:pk>` o `<int:pk>`

Sabiendo esto, **¿Cómo obtengo ese valor en mis vistas?**

Bien, en tu caso es bastante fácil, porque sobreescribes un método, lo cual nos permite adaptar la funcionalidad según nuestros requisitos

```
class StationGalleryListView(ListView):
    model = ImageStation
    template_name = 'station/gallery_station.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
            # Obtenemos el valor que nos pasan por la URL
            # En este caso lo hemos declarado con el nombre "pk"
            # No hace falta ni el if, ya que siempre le obligamos a pasar algún parámetro
            # en caso contrario el Django mismo le mandara un mensaje con un 404
            name = self.kwargs.get('pk') # self.kwargs['pk'] también funciona 
            object_list = self.model.objects.all().filter(station__id = name)
            return object_list
```

Pequeños detalles

```
self.model.objects.all().filter(station__id = name)
```

En este caso no necesitas todas las imágenes de la galería, si no algunas, por lo cual siempre es mejor usar `filter` por temas de performance.

```
self.model.objects.filter(station__id = name)
```

Puedes ver [aquí](https://github.com/django/django/blob/687b3d96c40d745371c64bca7fe6d46a4e7e379c/django/db/models/manager.py#L132) de como están escritos estos métodos.

Por otra parte cuando nos referimos a `self.request.GET` obtendremos los parametros que se pasan como [QueryString](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), es decir cuando tu URL se llama de la siguiente manera.

```
https://domain/gallery_station/1?q=Algo&q2=Algomás
```